# Is there software to automatically change song speed without transposing it

Tags: audio, music, bpm

Goal: *automatically adjusting speed (bpm) of a given set of MP3 files* in order to have a collection of music optimized to be heard when I am running. (I realized that I prefer to run with about 168 bpm in my ears).

Of course, I could have some software to detect BPM and then calculate and stretch/squeeze each song using Audacity or a similar tool, however, I'd prefer a solution which requires less manual operation.

Comment: First, find software to detect the BPM. Then, sox.

Comment: Hey, sox is a cool tool - thanks :) Still, it would be quite time consuming this way, I hoped for a solution which is as automated as possible. I think I'll have some more research, maybe I find a BPM detector with command line interface, so I could write a script to glue them together :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think **soundstretch** has the requirements. Command line based, it adjustes the song to the desired BPM. Try it because sometimes it estimates the wrong number of beats (rarely, it seems)

- [Someone who has a wiki about the topic](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2010/07/23/counting-bpm-beats-per-minute-on-linux)
- [Official soundstretch webpage](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/soundstretch.html)

Comment: Further, use `ffmpeg` or similar to convert between WAV and MP3.

Answer (score 0):

Try Mixxx.

> http://mixxx.org/features.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this cool piece of software. Unfortunately, it cannot help in achieving my goal, but interesting program nevertheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  It's free, open-source, and can load and save mp3 or almost anything directly.  Use the Change Tempo effect.